# Windows上のVMware Workstation 12 Playerで立てたサーバー（Linux, Apache）にドメインを使ってアクセスしたい

Tags: linux, apache, vmware

httpd.confのDocumentRootを`/srv/http/example`に変更し、ディレクトリ内にはindex.phpがあります。
IPアドレスは192.168.160.142が割り当てられています。
ホストOSのWindowsからのみ`http://192.168.160.142`でアクセスが可能です。
この状態から`http://example.com`でアクセスできるようにすべく、以下のことを試しました。

1. httpd.confに`ServerName example.com:80`の行を追加
2. hostsに`192.168.160.142 example.com`の行を追加
3. `hostname example.com`で一時的にホストネームを変更

しかし、ブラウザにはサーバーが見つかりませんと表示されます。
解決策がありましたらご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

単にホストOS(Windows)からだけアクセス出来ればよいのなら、Windowsのhostsファイルにエントリを追加してやればいいと思います。Windowsのバージョンによってファイルの保存場所が異なるので確認してください。

`192.168.160.142 hogehoge.com`

httpd.confのServerNameで設定したものはあくまでApache側での処理に使用するもので、Windows側には伝わりません(詳細は割愛しますがApacheのホスト名を設定するための項目でもありません)。

Comment: hostsの編集は行ったと質問に書いてあります

Comment: @suzukis 回答を付ける際には見落としていましたが、再度行った手順を見る限りはLinux側のhostsを編集しただけのように見えます